# Install packages through yum from file

Tags: linux, yum

Is there any way to install packages through yum from a file?

Something like:

yum -f packages.txt

I couldn't find anything in the man pages.

packages.txt would contain something like:

```
bash
bc
binutils
bzip2
bzip2-libs
ca-certificates
cairo
```

Comment: *why* `rpm -ivh filename` won't do it?

Comment: @HubertKario, yum will resolve dependencies.

Comment: @HubertKario Also, AFAIK, that installed `filename` as if it is an RPM package, but here `filename` is a list of package names that need to be fetched.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
xargs yum -y install < filename
```

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
yum install `cat <filename> | tr '\n' ' '`
```

As *should*:

```
yum install `cat <filename>`
```

I added the pipe to `tr` as a sanity check, just in case the environment is wacky.

**per a comment**:

```
yum install $(cat <filename>)
```

will also work, rather than using the backticks.

Comment: Just tried the exact same thing - interestingly enough, it doesn't seem necessary to remove the line breaks (although, of course, it works with them removed)

Comment: @cyberx86 - I did the `tr` bit out of paranoia :)

Comment: The accepted practice nowadays is to wrap Bash shell commands with $( foo bar) instead of backticks.

Comment: @AdrianK - thanks for the suggestion. I've been using backticks for a really long time ... it'll take some getting used to :)

Answer (score 0):

This [works](https://access.redhat.com/articles/10054):

```
yum localinstall /path/to/file.rpm
```